How can I fix poor video quality from VLC which occurred after upgrading from Debian Bullseye to Bookworm?
I'm getting very poor quality from VLC after upgrading from Debian 11 to 12, like it drops some frames and tries to recover from that every 10 seconds or so. Mplayer works like a charm by the way. How can I investigate the case?
VLC media player 3.0.21 Vetinari (revision 3.0.21-0-gdd8bfdbabe8)
VLC version 3.0.21 Vetinari (3.0.21-0-gdd8bfdbabe8)
Compiled by marillat on deb-multimedia.org (Jun 12 2024 05:33:04)
Compiler: gcc version 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14)

